# Why does 'anyDensity' have an effect on performance of rendering drawPath()?

Tags: android, view, draw

The core part is adding 200 points to a Path object and calling `drawPath()` after then, quite simple:

```
private Path mPath = new Path();
private Paint mPaint = null;
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mPoints.size() == 0) {
        generatePoints();
    }

    if (mPaint == null) {
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    mPath.rewind();

    for (int i = 0; i < mPoints.size(); i++) {
        int x = (int) ((int) (mPoints.get(i).x * mScale) + mOffsetX);
        int y = (int) ((int) (mPoints.get(i).y * mScale) + mOffsetY);
        if (i == 0) {
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
            mPath.lineTo(x, y);
        }
    }

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

I use `mScale` to control the size and `mOffsetX` `mOffsetY` to move lines around. When the `mScale` is small, all lines are visible in the screen, I can move it around smoothly, while it gets choppy when `mScale` increases with a situation where a large number of lines are not visible in the screen.

Weird thing is that if I change `anyDensity` to `false` in the Manifest.xml then no matter how large the `mScale` I set, the touch can be always smooth.

I want to know is there any difference in rendering `drawPath` between `anyDensity="true"` and `anyDensity="false"`. Since `anyDensity="false"` will make app look odd, is there any way to achieve the same smooth effect and set `anyDensity` to `true`.

Comment: @Rolbin It can not explain why does `anyDensity='false'` render fast.

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18312440/5803873) says, If `anyDensity` is false it disables pre-scaling.